# Running VBA Script to Automate Large Data Aggregation

Tags: excel, vba

[Sheet where info is copied from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCONn.png)
[Destination Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaaSH.png)
Am currently looking for the most efficient way to copy and paste data from one worksheet (which is an output of a report pulled from a third party system), into another sheet which is a steady state "legacy file" if you will. Essentially, the destination file is a repository of different years / months of data with 3 distinct categories along the column headers (for now we can call them x,y,z). These categories each have distinct attributes, in example let's focus on x, this will have 4 attributes attached to it, think

1. Customer,
2. Customer selling point
3. Product ID sold to customer
4. Product Name

based on the information pulled from the system. I need to find a way to:

1. Pull the data from one sheet to the other, starting first with the distinct attributes (which are text and numerical mixed), and based on the 3 distinct categories, then paste special value these column headers along the rows for each of the attributes

I am just taking this process over now, it is extremely time consuming and was being done manually previously and I am not willing to spend 2-3 hours doing something that can be automated. I have started on my code below, but am stuck on the pasting special values based on column headers:

```
 Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
 Dim wsRR As Worksheet
 Dim wsRRPiv As Worksheet
 Dim lcopylastrow As Long
 Dim lRRLastRow As Long
 
 
 
  
 
 
'Setting variables for report support workbook as well as download
'
 
    Set wsCopy = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsRR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsRRPiv = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot")
 
'This will activate the workbook and work sheet which as the data which will then be moved from  into this sheet
'
lcopylastrow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

lRRLastRow = wsRR.Cells(wsRR.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  

' Unmerging cells within download
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3:G" & lcopylastrow).UnMerge
    
' This section of code will introduce the copy and pasting necessary to get the data into the consolidation of the report. As the report can only handle two separate Copy and pastes at a time, this first section will focus on getting the correct data sets for the left most columns (Sales & Cases)
'


wsCopy.Range("A8:D" & lcopylastrow).Copy _
    wsRR.Range("C" & lRRLastRow)
    
wsCopy.Range("E8:E" & lcopylastrow).Copy _
    wsRR.Range("AR" & lRRLastRow)
    
wsCopy.Range("F8:F" & lcopylastrow).Copy _
    wsRR.Range("AR" & lRRLastRow)
    
    
    
    
    
wsCopy.Range("G8:G" & lcopylastrow).Copy _
    wsRR.Range("AR" & lRRLastRow)




    
End Sub
```

Comment: If it was previously taking 2-3 hours, I suggest adding in some `Application.Wait` and enjoying a nice coffee break as the macro "does work". That aside, what does "distinct attributes" mean? Are you filtering the data before, during or after the copy/paste? When you say Pivot, do you mean `PivotTable` or transpose? When you say "associated with" you mean the data is a total or a summary? Are you inserting formulas or calculating the results in VBA?

Comment: @Toddleson Thanks for the pointers on asking questions here, in case you can't tell I am a bit of a newbie to VBA in general. I have broken the question into 3 different parts, will attack two and 3 based on responses to 1.

Comment: Can you add an example of the both files? I'm not fully understanding your description.

Comment: @Toddleson Is there a way to add files here as an attachment?

Comment: No, Just take a screenshot of both sheets and add the images to the post. Make sure to remove any personal identification or private company information.

Comment: @Toddleson thanks just added two short images to hopefully add more clarity...please feel free to let me know if I should add more.

Comment: The 'source' and 'destination' screenshots don't seem particularly representative, for example in 'source' there's data for 2021 but in 'destination' there's no data for that year. P.S. Are you sure you need VBA?

Comment: @norie the destination file goes from 2017-ytd 2021 month by month. Given the size of the destination file (1 million rows) I’d say I do yes, but open to hear thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I will add to this answer and continue to improve it as I better understand your objectives.

When aggregating data into an existing table, a common and advisable strategy is to go row by row. That way, you can search the table to see if the record already exists, and you can either add to the existing record, overwrite it, or skip it.

I have written up an example of how you might go row by row with your files:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsRR As Worksheet
    Dim wsRRPiv As Worksheet
    Dim lcopylastrow As Long
    Dim lRRLastRow As Long
    
    
    'Setting variables for report support workbook as well as download
    '
    
    Set wsCopy = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsRR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set wsRRPiv = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot")
    

    lcopylastrow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    lRRLastRow = wsRR.Cells(wsRR.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    
    ' Unmerging cells within download
    '
      wsCopy.Range("A3:G" & lcopylastrow).UnMerge
      
    ' This section of code will introduce the copy and pasting necessary to get the data into the consolidation of the report. As the report can only handle two separate Copy and pastes at a time, this first section will focus on getting the correct data sets for the left most columns (Sales & Cases)
    '
    
    Const wsCopy_STARTING_ROW As Integer = 6 'First row containing data in wsCopy
    Const wsRR_STARTING_ROW As Integer = 5 'First row containing data in wsRR
        
    Dim i As Long
    For i = wsCopy_STARTING_ROW To lcopylastrow
        'For each row of data in wsCopy
        
        'save a reference to the current row
        Dim CurrentRow As Range
        Set CurrentRow = wsCopy.Rows(i)
        
        'Grab all data values from the current row
        'ASSUMES DATA IS IN COLUMNS 1 to 7 (A:G)
        Dim CustomerID As String, CostCenter As String, ProductID As String, ProductName As String, WSV As String, LBS_Sold As String, Tubes_Sold As String
        CustomerID = CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        CostCenter = CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        ProductID = CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        ProductName = CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
        WSV = CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
        LBS_Sold = CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value
        Tubes_Sold = CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value
        
        'Try to find the destination row in wsRR using the CustomerID and ProductID
        Dim rDestination As Range
        Dim j As Long
        For j = wsRR_STARTING_ROW To lRRLastRow
            'For each row in wsRR
            'Compare the customerID and ProductID in wsRR to the ones from wsCopy
            'ASSUMES CUSTOMER ID is in wsRR COLUMN B and PRODUCT ID is in wsRR COLUMN D
            If wsRR.Cells(j, 2) = CustomerID And wsRR.Cells(j, 4) = ProductID Then
                Set rDestination = wsRR.Rows(j)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If rDestination Is Nothing Then
            'If no destination row was found, add it to the bottom of wsRR
            Set rDestination = wsRR.Rows(lRRLastRow)
            'ASSUMES CUSTOMER ID to PRODUCT DESCRIPTION ARE IN wsRR COLUMNS B:E
            rDestination.Cells(2) = CustomerID
            rDestination.Cells(3) = CostCenter
            rDestination.Cells(4) = ProductID
            rDestination.Cells(5) = ProductName
            lRRLastRow = lRRLastRow + 1
        End If
        
        'At this point we have all the data from wsCopy and we have identified a destination row in wsRR
        'I don't know what to put in "METRIC" or what to do with Walled Sales Value, Sales Pounds, Tubes Sold
        'You can do stuff like
        'rDestination.Cells(1) = "WSV"
        'rDestination.Cells(10) = CDbl(WSV)
        'Which would put the string "WSV" in column A and then put the Walled Sales Value as a number into column J
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sending this over. Unfortunately due to size of the file, the macro caused it to crash. Rather then spend too much time trying to automate a rather old convention, I am going to try to parse the file out and try to utilize access or another database app. Thanks again for your time and help. I am definitely going to dig into what you've done here deeper. Hoping to be at this level of proficiency one day.